# Under @flow strict, what alternatives are there to Object for utility functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flowtype, strict

I am interested in switching my Flow code to `strict` type checking, but I have some low-level utility functions that deal with Objects generically, such as:

```
// @flow strict

const hasKey = (o: Object): (string => boolean) =>
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.bind(o);

const union = (os: Array<Object>): Object =>
  os.reduceRight((acc, o) => ({ ...acc, ...o }), {});
```

Since the Object type isn't allowed in strict mode, how do you declare types for functions that are explicitly supposed to operate on any generic Object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll actually be benefiting greatly from stricter typing, in this case. By using `Object` you are essentially turning the typing system *off* for all data that passes through these functions until they can be explicitly re-typed elsewhere. This means that you're currently losing a ton of typing information that you don't need to.

This is a textbook case for generics, which are documented [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/).

```
// @flow strict
const hasKey = <T: {}>(o: T): (string => boolean) =>
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.bind(o);

const union = <T: {}>(objects: Array<T>): T =>
  objects.reduce((acc, o) => ({ ...acc, ...o }), ({}: $Shape<T>));
```

The most important part of the above is the `: {}` in `<T: {}>`. These are *type bounds.* If a generic is a way of saying, "allow the user to pass any type they want, and store that type in a variable so that I can refer to it later," then type *bounds* are a way of saying "allow the user to pass any type they want, *as long as that type is a member of type X.*"

Because of the way [width subtyping](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/width-subtyping/) works, `{}` is the most generic object type. Effectively all objects are subtypes of `{}`. So `<T: {}>` basically means, "T should be any type that is an object."

Note that this is very different from `<T: Object>`, which basically means, "T is an object and from now on I'm not checking anything else about it." This means that we can do things like:

```
const o: Object = {};
console.log(o.some.member.that.doesnt.exist); // no error at compile time,
                                              // but obvious error at runtime
```

Unlike:

```
const o: {} = {};
console.log(o.member); // Error, we don't know about this member property!
```

So by telling flow that the argument is a subtype of `{}`, we are telling it that it has the basic API of an object. It has properties, it can be rest and spread, it can be string indexed, etc., *but nothing else.* Additionally, by storing the data type as the generic `T` and returning that type, we are maintaining the type information of the argument. This means that whatever we pass in as an argument, we will get the same type of thing out the other side (instead of a black box of mystery).

Comment: I was unaware of type bounds in generics! Does calling `reduceRight()` with a single argument and moving the empty initial object inside the passed function do anything substantial? I note that it changes the inferred return type from `{||}` (which Flow was getting wrong) to `T | {}` (which is the same as T when T is bounded to be {}, so I don't know why Flow is getting that wrong either).

Comment: Turns out you can't drop the second argument to `reduce()` because then you get "(node:51258) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value" when reducing over the empty array.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's gonna cause problems.

Comment: I updated the answer. I understand why using `{}` as the default by itself causes an error, but to be honest, I can't really explain why casting it as `$Shape<T>` resolves the error. But, this works in all cases as far as I can tell.

Comment: Sorry for not accepting this answer earlier. I ended up switching to TypeScript. >:-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can write your functions with flow generics. e.g.,

```
function union <T>(os: Array<T>): T { 
   ...
}
```

documentation: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/

Comment: Just using generics isn't good enough, because then you can pass in non-Object primitives, according to the type system.

Comment: @NicholasShanks You are correct, this is a very naive approach. 
Buy many operators and native functions well defined in flow. For example, for the "..." operator only allows object type.    e.g.,  `const x = {...1}` gives Error:(68, 11) object literal. Expected object instead of a number. Therefore, this function will only work with data types that can be used with the spread operator